# How do I make the contents of current clicked tabs always shown in different containers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's the link of my code [https://jsfiddle.net/vmzttpok/7/][1]

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#link').click(function(){
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

    $('#link').removeClass('current');
      $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

    $(this).addClass('current');
    $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
})
```

})

Problem is when I clicked tabs in different container, contents disappear in other container...

Comment: Put a complete yet minimal demo here, not on some other site. If you're asking a question on this site, why would you put your code somewhere else?

Comment: Best way, in my opinion, would be having a main container, and move your tabs out of sub-containers. Solves your problem, and avoids redundancy.

Comment: @crazy train is that a violation in stackoverflow? if yes, then i'm sorry I didn't know. I just prefer it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using the same class name, we've to implement logic using **$(this)**, based on this we can apply changes only to the specific container.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
        $(this).parent().find('li').removeClass('current');
        $(this).parent().siblings(".tab-content").removeClass('current');
            $(this).addClass('current');
            $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
        })
    })
```

For more info please visit - https://jsfiddle.net/vmzttpok/9/

Answer (score 0):

i see, thank you for answering! this worked. tried this too and worked in jsfiddle

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
        var p_id = $(this).closest('div').attr('id');

    $('#'+p_id+' ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
    $('#'+p_id+' .tab-content').removeClass('current');

    $(this).addClass('current');
    $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');

    })
})
```